# @IBOutlet is nil in selector method

Tags: swift, selector, iboutlet

I found a problem in my code which is very strange.
I made a UIButton programmatically and i add some target with #selector and @objc method.
But, in this @objc method, i can't access to another @IBOutlet, i always have this Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file.

this is my button which is well connected

```
@IBOutlet weak var btn_selectAllGamme: UIButton!
```

The code of the button

```
let btn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: Int(destinationController.view_gammePE.bounds.width/2+12), y: Int(destinationController.view_saison.bounds.height/2-30)+(k*55), width: 184, height: 40))
    btn.setTitle(val, for: .normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .semibold)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(choixSaison_click(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchDown_click(_:)), for: .touchDown)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dragExit_click(_:)), for: .touchDragExit)
```

And the selector :

```
@objc func touchDownGamme_click(_ sender : UIButton){
        self.btn_selectAllGamme.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Did you connect the IBOutlet in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes the UIButton is connected, i can access it in all others function but not in selector

Comment: you set up 3 targets, but none of them are `touchDownGamme_click`  where are you seeing the error?  and you don't actually add your new button to the view ` self.view.addSubview(btn)`  You need to show the code you're actually running, and be clear about where you're getting the error.  With what you've shown, the second button is never created, and even if it was, you don't set up the selector

Comment: I add the btn to his superview, it's not the problem!
I don't explain correctly, but i have some news :
I can't use the btn_selectAllGamme UIButton from anywhere but it wasn't nil in his @IBACTION.
In storyboard, i have the main view which is linked to a parentViewController and a lot of child views wich are all linked to the same childViewController and i think the problem is here

Comment: if your buttons are on different view controllers, then you should probably be looking at delegates - there are lots of good examples around like this one https://learnappmaking.com/delegation-swift-how-to/  If that's not what you're doing, you should find a way to explain your problem better